# Socket.io/Ws Event Does Not Work Properly

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, async-await, socket.io, ws

**Lets See Server Side Code First.**

```
io.on('connection', (socket) => {
     socket.on('message', async () =>{
     await sleep(10000); //This Function Takes 10s To Process
     console.log(++total)
  })
});
```

**Client Side**

```
socket.on('connect', () => {
     console.log('connected!');
     for(var i=0;i < 100000; i++){
       socket.emit('message', 'room1');
     }
});
```

Here I am trying to spam my server. Now Every Request Should Take 10s, But Here Only First Emit consumes 10 second and then every requests gets executed instantly.

Please Explain This Nature Of Event And Async-Await.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because Node.js is async.

What you did on the client is send 100000 messages almost at the same time, so the Node.js server receives all of these messages one by one and Socket.io calls your callback, in your callback you are doing `sleep` that I assume is just a wrapped `setTimeout`, so this particular callback waits for `setTimeout` to be executed, but here when Eventloop comes into play, while this callback waiting for the `setTimeout` other JS code is executed, so all of these 100000 messages are processed, and each of the callback waits for the `setTimeout`. So as a result after 10 seconds `setTimeout` callback will be called by the EventLoop, and then your code will be executed.

It can confuse you if you are used to working with e.g. Java, where each client has a dedicated process/thread, and hence `sleep` would block the whole proccess from execution.

You can read more about the event loop here  https://nodejs.dev/learn/the-nodejs-event-loop

UPD: You can see when your callbacks are actually called by means of adding a simple `console.log` before calling the `sleep` function.

Comment: First Of All, Thanks For Giving A Detailed Explanation, People Like You Makes Community More Better.

Comment: Suppose We Adding Some Data To Database, Client Spammed 10000 Data And We Want to add those data in order of message sent by client. Due To Difference in execution time taken by *add* function, every processes will be executed in different order. How To Tackle These Scenario .

Comment: I personally use queue architecture , Something Like Producer And Consumer Architecture, What Will Be Your Approach.

Comment: Yep using the Producer and Consumer approach can help. Just add the messages to the queue in the order of arrival and then process them one by one.

Comment: Ie there any other approach ?

Comment: You could ignore the queue and just handle the messages. Most of the time it will be handler properly in the order you received them, but yea there can be race conditions when speaking about async functions and so on. 

If someone spams you, you should probably just think about throttling or some DDoS Shield. Also, there is a question of app design, why a client can spam you? Maybe you should disable some buttons on the UI while you are waiting for the message result.

Comment: I am also a security researcher and app ui cant stop someone from ddos or spamming :) This is why i posted this question to learn more about different different approaches.

Comment: We Can't Handle Message Directly :) . At Last We Want Accurate System, And Each Error Can Cause Alot Of Problems. So There Should Be Any Proper Way. :

Comment: Queue sounds as a proper way, you can use AWS SQS for example.